# Continuous integration to local server

Tags: windows, git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, gitlab

I'm currently working on a couple projects that are being stored on a local `Gitlab`. Migrating the repos to `bitbucked` is on the roadmap.

Currently we are deploying the code manually onto our servers **manually** and I was wondering, what options I have for deploying the code into the local **Windows** machine, both on the `GitLab`(on premise) and `Bitbucked`(Cloud) options.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In gitlab, if you use gitlab CI, you can setup your runner to deploy to environments (usually by using a ssh script at the end of your build, or by triggering a webhook on your target environment).
Full doc can be found here :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html

For Bitbucket, the same principle should apply if you use their 'pipelines' which are very similar to gitlab CI runners.

Comment: I suppose it's doable when the server is on premise, but on the bitbucked, that is cloud based, will I need to expose the server to the internet? Or require to use some kind of utility like bamboo?

Comment: Yes if the code is built on the cloud, and you want to deploy it locally, you will have to expose your server to the internet :).  If you are worried about this last part, setting up a webhook on the server that would trigger a pull or a download of the artefacts would allow you to only expose your port 80.

Answer (score 0):

On the cloud there is good CI Windows service called [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/). We use it for running pywinauto tests, but it's suitable for many projects including private ones. It has very professional [tech support](https://github.com/appveyor/ci) guy Feodor Fitsner.